# Using mysqldump on hosted servers without directory 777 permision

Tags: php, mysql, database-backups

I'm trying to create a php file that a cron will access. This file will create a backup of the database it is connected to. To do this, it uses PHP's `exec()` and `mysqldump`

This all works fine, BUT, it only works if the directory it is writing has permissions `0777`. I've tested with different permissions, and it seems like only the world number needs to be 7. (or at least write and read I think)

The problem with this is, I don't want anyone but the server to be able to see this backup, since it contains user information! (even though this information is encrypted)
I've tried using `chmod` on the directory to make it 0777 only while writing the file, but it is unable to change the permissions, and this might be another security risk.

Is there any way to write this file to a directory with `0700` permissions? Or is there any other way that I'm not seeing right now...

Source code:

```
<?php
backup('notecms', 'root');
function backup($name, $user, $pass = NULL) {
  $filename='/note_db_backup_'.date('G_a_m_d_y').'.sql';
  if ($pass == NULL) {
    $result=exec('mysqldump notecms --single-transaction --user='. $user .' -r '. $filename . ' 2>&1', $output, $return_var);
  }
  else {
    $result=exec('mysqldump notecms --single-transaction --user='. $user .' -p='. $pass .' -r '. $filename . ' 2>&1', $output, $return_var);
  }
  if($return_var == 0){
    //return 0;
    if (!chmod($filename, 0600)) {
      die('could not change backup permissions');
    }
    deleteold();
  }
  else {
    print_r($output);
    global $backup_output;
    $backup_output = $output;
    //return 1;
  }
}

function deleteold() {
  $filecount = count(scandir("../backup/")) - 2;
  if ($filecount > 5) {
    $files = glob( '../backup/*' );
    array_multisort(
    array_map( 'filemtime', $files ),
    SORT_NUMERIC,
    SORT_ASC,
    $files
    );
    unlink($files[0]);
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: Each user has their own crontab just make sure the owner of that directory is the one that is running the cron job.

Comment: Consider rewriting this script in bash to remove the PHP dependency. Or if you want to keep it in PHP, be sure to escape interpolated variables ($user, $pass and $filename) with http://php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php

Comment: Also the function backup is working on the root directory. You have a hardcoded path on the $filename definition, try to pass the $filename='note_db_backup_'.date('G_a_m_d_y').'.sql'; without the slash

Comment: @WouterH Since this is going to stay in PHP, thanks! Even though these values shuld never be something like that, I will implement it for safety!

Comment: @PerroVerd You're right. This was how it was initially, so this is not the problem. Thanks for pointing that out though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no reason for the permissions to be `0777`. You need the user that executes the script to have read/write access to the directory, so make sure that user owns the directory and all you need is `0700`.

Comment: Okay, I guess I should use `chown()` for that. How would I go on doing this. This file could end up on lots of different servers, and I'm afraid that the owner has to be different in a lot of cases.

Comment: The same way you deploy the file and install the cron job. Ideally you create a backup user on each server, execute this file as the backup user, and write to the backup user's home directory.

Ideally you'd have an ansible script that uploads the php file, creates the backup user with its home directory, installs the cron job, etc.

Comment: The way this will work: This code is part of a cms. the cms will install this file, along with others, and possibly set-up the cron job. How would I set users and let them run this file, with only php. I won't have access to the server adminpanel, and would like this to be completely without interaction from the user.

Comment: Then I don't think there is a solution to do this generically and securely. If you do not control the server's that you are deploying to it is also rather risky to rely on both `exec` and `mysqldump` to be available.

Comment: That seems to be the case here then... How about writing this function in pure php, using normal queries to make the backup file. This would mean I don't need both `exec` and `mysqldump`. Do you think this would work?

Comment: That would definitely work for your backup, but you still have the issue of storing the files securely. Really, that's something that the person managing the system has to take care of. I'd suggest having a configuration setting of where you write the backups to, and then tell the user to secure that backup directory and to ensure that the cron user has write access to that directory.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117725/discussion-between-exentory-web-development-and-wouterh).

Comment: Marked as answer because it helped me the most!

Answer (score 1):

Your script must run as the owner of the directory or be able to sudo to that owner to run the script.  As you need it done on a number of servers, you should talk to the system administrator to have them set that up.

They can set it up to work just for that task and likely have a method to push it to all servers..

Comment: How would I use `chown()` if the file is used on different servers. I don't know what kind of servers, but this would mean the owners are different for this right?

Comment: For maintainability and security, most servers of the same OS should be identical in their configuration.  If you dont know what kind of servers, I don't see how you can make sure it works or even test it.